# When do we use 'have been +adjective and have been +noun? When to use?

Tags: expressions

What is meaning of I've been respectful? and what is meaning of 'reflecting on  a year gone by?

Comment: I have been respectful means there was a pattern *over time* of showing respect.

Comment: When do we use have /has been +adjective or have/has been +noun?

Comment: He *has been*, and she *has been*. Have noun? Not much, maybe we have success, we have liftoff, we've got trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second example is "I've been reflecting on a year gone by."

One is an adjective and the other an idiom. 
*Reflecting on* just means to consider or think carefully about a thing. Here you have been thinking about the previous year. One could use it another way such as: On reflection your question was fine and the answer a bit more involved than I thought.

@Yosef Very well stated.